# Oracle Apex Interactive report sending emails as htm not CSV or XLSX

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an apex application that I configured the Emails to, but when i get the emails i get them in htm format not csv or xlsx. Is this something to do with the SMTP server settings or is it a configuration that i have to correct in APEX administration?
Any help is appretiated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Email" output format feature of APEX Interactive Reports will send the report in HTML format. This cannot be changed.

If you want a CSV or XLSX file, you need to choose "CSV" or "XSLX" as your download format.

Out of the box, there is no option to email a CSV or XLSX. You would need to code this yourself.